# AWS Amplify support for the Next js Image API

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

[Amplify's documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/hosting/nextjs/q/platform/js#deploy-and-host-an-ssg-only-app) shows that current version of Amplify does not support [Next.js's Image API](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image) yet. Does anyone know if Amplify team has a plan to support Image API if so, when that will be released?

Answer (score 5):

It appears Amplify hosting now supports Next.js version 11, which includes:

- Automatic image optimization
- incremental static regeneration
- script optimization

More info https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/08/aws-amplify-hosting-support-next-js-version-11/